# Angular project is not runing after update

Tags: json, angular, typescript

I'm new to angular, I'm trying to build my project after an update from angular 6 to 8, however for some reason I'm having 2 warnings that I don't understand, I've searched all over the internet but non of the solutions worked, appreciate your assistance.

```
WARNING in D:/Spark/doPayroll Backup/dopayroll-front-end/src/app/banks/addbank.model.ts is part of 
the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.

WARNING in D:/Spark/doPayroll Backup/dopayroll-front-end/src/environments/environment.prod.ts is 
part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
  "types": []
},
"exclude": [
  "test.ts",
  "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.spec.json

```
{
"extends": "../tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
"outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
"types": [
  "jasmine",
  "node"
]
},
"files": [
  "test.ts",
  "polyfills.ts",
  ],
"include": [
  "**/*.spec.ts",
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To resolve the warning:

```
"environment.prod.ts" is part of the TypeScript compilation but it's unused.
Add only entry points to the 'files' or 'include' properties in your tsconfig.
```

in your component:

```
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
...
getProjects() {
// observable
if(!environment.production) {
    console.log(environment.apiUrl);
}
this.callback$ = this.apiService.get(environment.apiUrl);
```

in your environment.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  apiUrl: 'https://abc.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/projects'
};
```

in your environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  apiUrl: 'https://abc.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/prod/projects'
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the previous angular version of which you have worked and try to install the same version by using the specific version install command

Use the below command:

replace the 6.1.1 with the specific version,

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@6.1.1
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add this to your tsconfig.app.json :

```
"include": [
        "src/**/*.ts"
    ],
 "enableIvy": false
```

check this [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) for tsconfig

Comment: I'm still getting the same warnings

Comment: try also to disable Ivy because it's enabled by default in version 8
look at the updated code.
https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/1853

Comment: I actually added this piece of code but still getting the same exact warnings, any other thoughts ?

Comment: try to add .ts  "src/**/*.ts"

Answer (score -1):

**environment.prod.ts is part of the typescript compilation but it's unused**

**tsconfig.app.json**

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "environments/*",
    "test.ts", 
    "**/*.spec.ts",
  ]
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank for the answer. Could you please explain what is wrong with the original config, and why yours fix the problem ?

This could help people in the same situation